# Copy 3 million S3 files to specific folders

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 3 million files in a single folder in my s3 bucket. I want to copy those files to specific folders within the same bucket depending on their assignment in my database. What is the most feasible way to do this.

I have this code which creates a copy request with the Javascript AWS SDK:

```
let copyRequest = {
  CopySource: encodeURI("bucket-name" + "/" + fileToMove.rows[0].Container + "/" + 
  fileToMove.rows[0].FileId),
  Bucket: "bucket-name",
  Key: encodeURI(new-folder-name-based-on-specific-file + "/" + fileToMove.rows[0].FileId)
}

// Copy files over
await s3Client.copyObject(copyRequest).promise();
```

Is there an AWS service or a way to batch these files as 3 million individual copy requests doesn't seem feasible, serial atleast.

Comment: Read about [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/batch-operations/).

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 Batch Operations can perform actions on large quantities of objects.

From [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-copy-object.html):

> The **Copy** operation copies each object that is specified in the **manifest**. You can copy objects to a bucket in the same AWS Region or to a bucket in a different Region. S3 Batch Operations supports most options available through Amazon S3 for copying objects. These options include setting object metadata, setting permissions, and changing an object's storage class.

You *should* be able to specify the current Key and the new Key in the Manifest File (but I haven't tried it myself).

Since you have this information in your database, you would need to export data from the database to create the manifest file. You can then provide that file to the Batch Operations job.

I suggest that you start by creating a manifest with just two objects (with different target folders). If that works, then you can make a larger file. Note that the Key of an object includes the folder, so the existing Key would be `folder1/foo.txt` and the new Key would be `folder2/foo.txt`.